# jQuery - Toggle children

Tags: jquery

I have looked all over stackoverflow for the answer to this, and I'm sure its just something stupid that I'm doing.

I have a bunch of divs that only show the heading until the div is clicked, and then the child span should smoothly slide down.  When the div is clicked again, the span should hide.

The toggle is working, however the slide down component is not smooth (just instantly appears on the page).

Here is the html for one of the blocks..

```
<div class="masterscourse">
    <h3>IPM 7790: Special Topics</h3>
    <span class="coursedescription">
    This course provides students an opportunity to explore topics not specifically addressed in a regular course offering, and that are of interest to practitioners and students
    </span>
</div>
```

The jQuery..

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.masterscourse span').hide();
    $(".masterscourse").click(function(){
        $('span', this).slideToggle('normal');
    });
    });
</script>
```

I feel like this should be relatively straightforward, so I'm sure its something dumb that I am doing.  Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: try using `slideToggle('slow')`

Comment: You can't animate the height of inline elements like span.  Use an element with display:block like a div.

Comment: Exactly - @MikeEdwards is spot on, see http://jsfiddle.net/z9pAW/

Comment: Mike, Thanks for the response.  As soon as you said this, I thought "Of course thats it!" and went to change my code.  Unfortunately, no luck.  for some reason it still does work.. **EDIT** I take it back .. this did work.  Thanks!  I why it wasn't working initially.  Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that inline elements don't play nice with height animations. An easy fix would be to give the `span` a style of `display:block`:

http://jsfiddle.net/AmKVd/

```
span.coursedescription {
    display:block;
}
```

You could also use a `div` instead of a `span`.

Comment: Thanks for this... Both yours and Mike Edwards comment was correct and helped me solve this.